# Free jqGrid 4.9.0 - Advanced Search Dialog (mutli param search) is changing location until exit the screen

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

This bug is happening only on Free jqGrid 4.9.0 (When I'm switching back to Free-jqGrid 4.8.0 all is working well).

I couldn't recreate it on jFiddle, so it might be due to the fact I have multiple grids on the same page (maybe).

The bug:

The advance search dialog have thier style 'top' and 'left' defaulted to 0px both, so that they apear by default at the upper left of the grid when user click on the search button.

Now, if you close the dialog, and click on the search button again, the 'top' and 'left' are being re-calculated somehow, and the dialog goes up -228.1875px for 'top' and -5px for 'left'.  the next time I repeat this flow, the dialog just vanished from the screen (cause it gets -500px or something).

This happens on all my 5 grids.  Same behavior.  the dialog keeps re-calculate it's position with every re-opening.

I started doing reverse engineering to find out where are those lines in 4.9.0 that cause to this behavior, and found out it's due to the function `savePositionOnHide` (line 9896 in jquery.jqgrid.src.js), within the block: `this.data(propName, {`

**if I replace:**

```js
top: top,                 //parseFloat($w.css("top")),
left: left,               //parseFloat($w.css("left")),
```

**with**

```js
top: getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "top"),             //parseFloat($w.css("top")),
left: getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "left"),               //parseFloat($w.css("left")),
```

That I copied from 4.8.0, all is working well.

So I was just wondered, if this indeed a bug, or something else I'm missing.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post the demo which can be used to reproduce the bug? I can't reproduce the problem. The changes was made for the case that jqGrid could be inside of dialog or some other div with `position: absolute`. The changes from 4.9.0 worked correctly in all my tests, but one can't use all possible test cases of cause.

Comment: I failed to re-create it for a demo, sorry.  I can only see it on my environment.  I'm not using position:absolute, so if you say there is no risk with the changed I did, than that's good enough for me.

Comment: It would be interesting to localize the origin of the problem. I suppose that you set some options like `jqModal`, `modal`, `toTop` of searching dialog or you set some properties of `$.jgrid.jqModal` (`toTop: false` or something like that). One can of cause use `recreateFilter: true` option to ignore previously saved position. It will be sure solve the problem, but it would be interesting for me to localize the test case when the code of 4.9.0 work incorrect. One need just have the demo which reproduces the code and to debug the code to find the reason.

Comment: I made it.  http://jsfiddle.net/bnbdyn0c/  Just click on btn2, and close the dialog, than click on btn2 again, close it, click on btn2 again.. You will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report and the demo which demonstrates the problem! I agree that the code is buggy. I fixed the code of `savePositionOnHide` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L23-L33)) from

```js
savePositionOnHide = function (propName, frmgr, h) {
    var $w = h.w, $form = $(frmgr), toTop = h.c.toTop, offsetGbox,
        top = getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "top"),
        left = getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "left");
    // we use below .style.height and .style.width to save correctly "auto" and "100%" values
    // the "px" suffix will be saved too, but it's not a problem 
    if (toTop) {
        offsetGbox = $w.closest(".ui-jqgrid").offset();
        top -= offsetGbox.top;
        left -= offsetGbox.left;
    }
    ...
}
```

to the following

```js
savePositionOnHide = function (propName, frmgr, h) {
    var $w = h.w, $form = $(frmgr), toTop = h.c.toTop, offsetGbox, offset, top, left;
    if (toTop) {
        offsetGbox = this.closest(".ui-jqgrid").offset();
        offset = $w.offset();
        top = offset.top - offsetGbox.top;
        left = offset.left - offsetGbox.left;
    } else {
        // we use below .style.height and .style.width to save correctly "auto" and "100%" values
        // the "px" suffix will be saved too, but it's not a problem 
        top = getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "top");
        left = getCssStyleOrFloat($w, "left");
    }
```

and [committed](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/cb1747a7d743807cd4a3cca78b094db22633bd8c) the changes to the main code on [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). [The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnbdyn0c/) which you posted use the code from GitHub directly and it start work correctly after I committed the fix.